# Running parse_url() on a string that may not contain the protocol

Tags: php, url, parse-url

I'm trying to get the domain name and TLD (no subdomain) from a user-input URL string which may or may not have protocol, directories, subdomains, filenames, etc.

In other words, given any of the following:

```
example.com
www.example.com
sub.example.com
example.com/whatever/hey.html
http://example.com
https://subdomain.example.com
ftp://example.com/whatever/hey.html
```

I should always end up with: `example.com`.

Right now this is what I am doing:

```
$hostParts = explode('.', parse_url($URL, PHP_URL_HOST));
$tld = array_pop($hostParts);
$domain = array_pop($hostParts);
$domain = $domain . "." . $tld;
```

However, if a URL is provided without the protocol, it breaks. Why is `parse_url` failing to get the host in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition a URL contains a protocol or scheme.  Check for // and if not present prepend // to the string.  This may be different in PHP < 5.4.7 so maybe add http:// if no protocol.

Comment: I can see that you're right. Here's the code I used to do it: 
`if(strpos($URL,"://")===false && substr($URL,0,1)!="/"){
        $URL = "http://" . $URL;
    }`
Just put that before the first line of the code, and it works.

Comment: Wee bit simpler, perhaps: `$url = ( strpos( $urlString, "//" ) === false ) ? "//$urlString" : $urlString;`