# Input url validation php

Tags: php, function, parse-url

I have problem with this code:

```
    $parse = parse_url($url); //$url is POST from input field
    $urls = $parse['host'];

    $domain = array('mydomain.com', 'mydomain.net');

    if (!in_array($urls, $domain)) {

       echo 'invalid URL';
    }
```

Checking url, if not in array, give error if yes continue....
I see all similar thread but no one fix my problem.

P.S the problem is: Only give Invalid URL (in case when url is correct and in case when URL is wrong)

e.x url: `mydomain.com/u/123-test` need to be valid url

Comment: show us an example of an invalid URL that should be valid

Comment: e.x url: `mydomain.com/u/123-test` need to be valid

Comment: https://3v4l.org/Vcq8s it behaves as expected with this URL

Comment: make sure you have `http(s)://` at the beginning of the string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running parse\_url() on a string that may not contain the protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597849/running-parse-url-on-a-string-that-may-not-contain-the-protocol)

Comment: Yes, i have http/s but not working...

Comment: @Tomy Show a reproducible example. Add a definition of `$url` in the code, not `$_POST` because we can't run that.

Comment: @Tomy Check the link I posted, it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason it is not working because your url doesn't contain the **scheme** `http(s)` part. With the `http(s)://`, when you try to `parse_url()` it returns **path** value not the **host** value

```
<?php
$url = 'http://yourdomain.com/u/123-test';  //$url is POST from input field
$url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$domain = array('yourdomain.com', 'yourdomain.net');
if (!in_array($url, $domain)) {
     echo 'invalid URL';
    }else{
     echo 'valid URL';
}
?>
```

> PHP Parse URL - Domain returned as **path** when **protocol** prefix not
>   present

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/nUCfH

Comment: This alters the original input. Additionally the `path` as the added note suggests won't work because it contains directories. I'd suggest the dup and prepend the protocol when not present.